# Why don't we have a brainstorming/discussion site?

Tags: feature-request, new-users, split-stack-overflow

Can we have a learning/brainstorming/discussions (basic newbie questions) site? Just a suggestion, please do consider.

1. Usually most questions asked by new members have very limited scope for research, but still there are members who are good enough and interested enough to spend time in making the newbie understand what actually the code is doing, rather than just give a one line link to a tutorial or better code. Not all but many learners like to have discussions and not just "working code".
2. This will reduce the number of possible duplicates as most users try to find code specific answers as compared to concept dependent answers.
3. Community rules on SO are strict and still users post very silly questions (even I have when trying to understand a new concept).
4. Have this site specifically for concept oriented, but code supported questions rather than code oriented questions.
5. Site providing learning opportunities through discussions (please don't say "refer to the documentation").

Why traditional methods are obsolete:

1. Documentation (I know it takes loads of work to prepare and format it)
   when I want to achieve a task, it's dependent on so very different platforms and technologies, reading documentation for all of them is impossible, documentation depends on you reading previous chapters too for you to understand.
2. Online tutorials (yes bloggers do put in effort to code examples):
   But the code contains a lot of bugs, very little relevant explanation and usually are outdated and there are better ways in achieving the said task (still online sources are great place if you just want to copy paste the code).

Please do say if there is already a place to learn concepts rather than just code.
(I'm an electrical engineering graduate, but equally passionate about bits and bytes and null characters, hence I needed an online and friendly space to improve my skills, Stack Exchange has been great community for me to learn, thank you for all your help).