# Introducing new concepts to be discussed

Tags: discussion

Can you please let new ideas be discussed and judged on your forums? I presented a solution to improve password hashing and it has been labeled off topic. As I see this forum generally does not support brainstorming.

Comment: StackOverflow **_is not_** a forum. This is a key point to understand. General discussion question are off-topic for the site. We want _specfic_ programming problems. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: What gave you any indication that's what Stack Overflow is for? SO is strictly a question and answer site. Nowhere does it state it is meant for brainstorming.

Comment: My point is to let ideas be discussed.

Comment: but we DON'T do "discussions" here. It's always been that way, and clearly explained in our help center and related articles... not sure why you'd think this is a proper place for this...

Comment: I come to SO because I can get a concise answer. I don't want to have to wade through a bunch of crap - SO is useful because we attempt to keep the signal to noise ration high.

Comment: I am suggesting it should consider that option.

Comment: *Does it really results in mathematically heavy protection of hash reversal?* - Is there any way for other users to objectively determine whether the answer to this is yes or no or would they have to guess?

Comment: Well i must admit i havent read terms and condutions. I am brand new here. Sorry for violating your rules. Should i delete my post or it is automatical?

Comment: @BlaiseBlack and why should we consider it? What added value would it give to the site? Considering we want a "Low noise, high signal" website, having "discussions" around DOESN'T DO IT. Lemme reverse the question: Why do you want that to be hosted HERE absolutely?

Comment: Your site's structure would very wel be suited to judge new ideas and criticism as well.

Comment: Note that votes on Meta don't affect your reputation. The system doesn't automatically delete questions before 30 days though high rep community members can vote to delete questions.

Comment: @BlaiseBlack actually, while the structure fits, the goal of the site doesn't. Stack was built to be a repository of high level knowledge. Discussions and criticism doesn't do that for the goal of the site. The intent of the site is that each question should be useful to OTHERS finding your question on Google. I don't see how "I coded this, is it good?" would be helpful to anyone Googling or looking for a fix to their issue

Comment: As for understanding how the site works, start with [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and all the pinned articles in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) (which is really more like a user manual for the site).

Comment: @BSMP i discussed it with a mathematician and an IT sec expert and 'yes' they simply said. So i wanted to ask a larger Community of experts.

Comment: @Patrice doesn't Google find it by the post's title line?

Comment: Well, we don't allow questions that are primarily opinion based so unless it's possible for someone to prove whether your idea results in mathematically heavy protection of hash reversal, using solely the description and image provided, then it's off-topic here.

Comment: @BlaiseBlack not exactly sure how that relates to what I said? I feel like I'm missing something

Comment: Patrice isn't arguing your post wouldn't be findable, they're arguing your post isn't useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't we have a brainstorming/discussion site?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267282/why-dont-we-have-a-brainstorming-discussion-site)

Comment: Every time I look at a discussion forum, I end up wading through piles of noise, follow-up questions, clarifying questions, and "me too!" comments before I find the actual answer. That's why I like Stack Overflow better.

Comment: @EJoshuaS Me too!

Answer (score 16):

> Can you please let new ideas be discussed and judged on your forums?

Stack Overflow ***is not a forum***. That is a very important point to understand. What may be suitable for a normal forum site, is likely *not* suitable content for Stack Overflow.

We want specific programming questions, that are researched, have an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if needed, and are not opinionated. We're trying to essentially create a giant repository of knowledge that is useful to a wide audience, present and future. Discussions and criticism simply wouldn't fit the goal of the site.

[Here is specifically what is on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) per the help center:

> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

Unfortunately, your question doesn't meet any of those criteria for on-topic-ness. Any answers would most likely be solely opinionated. And furthermore, your question isn't very likely to help any future visitors as it is very local.

While what you are suggesting sounds good in practice, and I admit it would be interesting to be able to simply discuss certain topics with fellow programmers, it really wouldn't work in Stack Overflow's current form and simply wouldn't fit its mission.

You could [try chat though](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/). We're much more flexible about what can be posted there, and what's off-topic for the main site perhaps could be posted there instead.