# New tag "merge request" to be used website wide

Tags: feature-request, tags, meta

I was scouring the meta SO and I found these gems:

1. [Why opinion-based questions cannot be answered or implemented here?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274762/why-opinion-based-questions-cannot-be-answered-or-implemented-here)
    a. [Is there a less restrictive Stack Exchange site specially suited for not too specific questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252777/is-there-a-less-restrictive-stack-exchange-site-specially-suited-for-not-too-spe)
2. [Why don't we have a brainstorming/discussion site?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267282/why-dont-we-have-a-brainstorming-discussion-site)
3. [Is there a less restrictive Stack Exchange site specially suited for not too specific questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252777/is-there-a-less-restrictive-stack-exchange-site-specially-suited-for-not-too-spe)
4. [Where can I ask questions that don't fit or are off-topic for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254567/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-dont-fit-or-are-off-topic-for-stack-overflow)

And so far, every of the questions has answers, and some of them loop back to each other (example with 1a, and 4). I doubt that anyone who asked a question had actually gone through all those links after the **marked as duplicate** flag was applied.

So I would like to request here on Meta Stack Overflow a "merge request" tag. This could benefit the website in reducing clutter and flagging circles. This "merge request" could be then tied (by title of the question) to the user profiles, questions, answers...

## In the question examples above:

This feature should give credibility to delete a question if it is already answered a bunch of times (4 in this case) and expanding searching options for questions that are phrased in specific way.

## For user accounts:

This feature could reduce the number of inactive users, by merging old with new accounts or simply merging accounts that are inactive by some measure into single community bot account. This way any user who wishes to ask one question, can simply post one question *n* times via the community account.

## For answers:

This feature could migrate answers and make clear and structured search options (from Google) having search options focused on one question instead of splitting into several other ones that have same/similar answer.

---

Merging should benefit the website :

1. Questions: quoting, formatting or html meta tags containing full text (or fragments) to expand the searching options for Google - *focusing traffic from multiple questions on a single one*.
2. User accounts: I don't know how this is generally done, but deleting of inactive accounts should be an priority. *Having accounts that are inactive for *n*+ years doesn't help when users are querying their data*.
3. Answers: simply merging the answers with a quote of the title in the header. So users can have context on that answer - thus *eliminating asking questions in multiple ways, and enabling the new users to find questions faster and fewer dupes.*

Comment: You might have an answer already here: [What is a merged question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158066/what-is-a-merged-question)

Comment: ... and https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts. But you are all over the place with this FR.

Comment: How are inactive users *harmful*?

Comment: FR ?
  
@user202729 they are harmful since whenever we have discussion here based on user experience, or  any other statistic, users often query the website to find data that then can influence the opinion/suggestion etc. Inactive users influence the data validity.

Comment: And they can just exclude inactive users from the query. Last active is public information.

Comment: Sure, but the query ( at least from complaints i've read here ) can't handle an large data. So having bunch of inactive users limits the functionality of query. And inactiveness can't be always filtered, since filtering depends on context of the query.

Comment: And just to be clear, i am proposing an "merge request" so users can recommend merging of something, it is much clearer that "merge a", "merge b" .... votes and mod influence can help govern this behaviour and implementation.

Comment: @yivi if it is still to broad i can really just edit it to ask for merge request without any benefits listed below and examples.

Comment: "FR" = "feature request"...

Comment: @Danilo Currently, only moderators can actually merge questions. This can be requested through raising a custom moderator flag and explaining. Note that the requirements for merging are *significantly* higher than for closing as a duplicate. Basically, all answers must be equally applicable on both answers *without modification*.

Comment: @Danilo It's really not clear to me what you're asking for here. Is the extent of what you're asking for the creation of a [meta-tag:merge-request] tag? Note that the tags: [meta-tag:merge-accounts] and [meta-tag:merged-questions] already exist.

Comment: Well i did figure there is some sort of mechanism behind merging. Thank you for explaining, didn't know the mech behind it. I was proposing something more along of directing moderating attention to specific merging type issues. I trust mods to make an valid decision, that is why main proposition was about making a new tags. By directing mods attention to high count questions, we can help mods by pointing out aspects that aren't flagged and perhaps are needed by comunity but don't fill every requirement.

Comment: The way those tags function now is similar to feature-request-tags, feature-request-votes and etc. I am proposing to join them under 1 umbrella - except [merged-questions] since that it seems works best with questions that are already merged. As I went to your merge-request link i saw no questions tagged as such, and I didn't see any merge-request when i tried to tag this question. Otherwise I wouldn't write it. If there is some other idea behind that link, please explain

Comment: @Danilo The [meta-tag:merge-request] tag doesn't exist at this time. The 0 questions of the tag is what is displayed when the tag doesn't exist. You can go to the [tags search page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags) and enter "merge" to see those tags which include the text "merge".

Comment: @Danilo BTW: If you want someone to know that you've made a change or left a comment, you need to `@` ping them with their username in the comment (maximum one user per comment). For example, for me it would be `@Makyen`. If you don't do so, then nobody is notified of any change you make or comment you leave (except in some [specific circumstances (see: "Replying in comments")](/editing-help#comment-formatting)). I'm mentioning this because I don't want you to feel that changes/comments you make are being ignored.This [meta post](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020) has more information.

Comment: @Makyen honestly the last comment means a lot to me. It is really rare to get the feeling that someone is having your best interest now a days. I know about that functionality... and i've used it above. But thanks. So far, i've been commenting in less than a minute with other users - while they were still on the page, so pinging someone seemed like a nuisance. Cindy(yivi) even corrected every edit i did. It just seems that very little users have opinion on this topic. The globe hasn't revolved yet fully so i am guessing that there should be some engagement tomorrow morning ( 6 hrs for me ).

Comment: @Danilo Thanks for the ping :-). Unfortunately, without pinging you never know if the person is going to see a new comment, even if they are currently viewing the page (which you never know for sure). As for getting other people's opinions, you should keep in mind that there's *substantially* less visibility for questions on Meta then there once was. The removal of "Hot Meta Posts" means that people have to go looking for meta posts, rather than rely on seeing a random selection show up in the sidebar. While I haven't seen quantification of the effects, the intent was to reduce viewers.

Comment: @Makyen how far does decreased visibility tracks? A day, a week, a month ago? I saw the post was posted month ago, but i didn't find anything about release date.

Comment: @Danilo Hot Meta Posts was removed on the same day as, actually slightly prior to, [the announcement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387546/we-re-removing-hot-meta-posts-from-stack-overflows-sidebar-for-now-moderator), which was on 2019-07-23.

Comment: I'm completely confused by this proposal and reasons behind it. I don't see why "inactive" users has to be removed (and why it is "priority"). I don't get what "can simply post one question n times via the community account" does and how it makes less duplication... I don't see circular duplicate links between questions (maybe there are some somewhere due to bugs... but I don't think one can easily set it up)...

Comment: @Makyen I got a hint of PTSD when I saw the link to the HMP being removed

Comment: @YvetteColomb I'm really sorry to hear that, and sorry my comment added stress for you. Unfortunately, I understand at least a part of what you're feeling. Thinking about the situation is quite unpleasant for me too, as it probably is for a lot of us here. I expect that it's significantly worse for you and the rest of the moderators.

Comment: @Makyen you didn't do anything wrong linking. It was just interesting to observe my own reaction... yeh it's been pretty hectic at times since becoming a mod. Our batch were elected and then wham the whole site was tipped upside down with the welcoming blog. It's been a bit of a roller coaster since then. It "seems" to be calm atm... do you think? Or are we in the eye of some storm I'm now used to?

Comment: @YvetteColomb It does seem to be calm at the moment. People are adapting to the new status quo. As to the future, unfortunately, all we really can do is wait and find out. What will happen is largely up to factors which we either don't know, many of which we *can't* know, or which we can't control or affect. My hope is that all sides get better at maintaining relationships, which would help significantly in navigating through any future difficulties.

Comment: @Alexei , there are users who ask a question and then bolt, there are users who ask a question and then return. If you gave an community (that doesn't have SO accounts) an possibility to ask a question without actually making account (under community account), you would have massive reduction among abandoned  user acc , and you will have an focused attention that people who would join SO would join because of community, not because they need an answer. That is the first reason why having (by bot or something) merging inactive accounts would be beneficial. Another reason is:

Comment: Another reason is that when people query data , it is too easy to fake the data by removing "redundant" or "unnecessary" data. If you wish to show your point by querying the website (as many do) it is easy to push the ties in your corner by careful data manipulation. That is the main fact. For example, you wish to prove that people with low rep are larger in numbers that people with high (1K+) rep. In that case, you can just "last time seen" to 10 years, instead of 1 or 2 years, and show graph instead of the code.

Comment: But if you remove inactive users, there is very little chance that someone can use those zombie data to push/pull the polles.   
  
@Makyen "In the eye of the hurricane, there is quiet ... for the moment... a yellow sky." Well i can give you my experience since my first question was on that fateful day (my luck) and it had very bad reception, but since then... less votes ... more engagement. I honestly have an experience, that more people willing to talk than argue are present in questions to day.

Comment: And @Makyen to build upon last topic we had. I like that my question so far has 0 votes. In my mind that is how it is supposed to be. It is normal for people to ask questions, protest or ask me to clarify my point. This way i can say that 100+ people saw my post, from which 100+ didn't see any benefits to my question, and 4 of them  are willing to poke some holes. So votes in that manner reflect if question is beneficial to the website(up vote), has no benefit (no vote) or can harm the website (down vote). I prefer that over personal opinion votes any time. This way i can stand behind my case.

Comment: @Danilo About your comment that people aren't responding to the question, even though we read/edited it: To be honest, I haven't really understood what problem you perceive and how the proposal should help. (I can correct basic grammar without understanding the underlying logic :-)) And from what I do understand, it's simply not a topic I feel strongly enough about to comment (or answer). From what I've seen in other comments, quite a few people may feel the same.

Comment: @Cindy i think that perhaps you didn't follow through with conversation behind Makyen and me. Makyen told me i should ping people , because the thought i felt that lack of votes and answers ment that my question was ignored. I just reassured him that it isn't how i felt. There isn't a problem, or issue. Honestly :D

Comment: I did follow, but not very closely. So, yes, I did have the impression you thought it was being ignored. But, indeed, you must "ping" :-)

Comment: @Danilo BTW: for the tag to be created, there needs to be at least one question on which it should be placed. If a tag isn't on any questions, then the tag is deleted by the system within 24 hours. In addition, IIRC, if a tag is on only one question, then it is deleted by the system after 6 months. For more on automatic tag deletion, please see: [What are all the reasons a tag can be eliminated automatically?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121191)

Comment: Interesting , so to create a tag i should approach by generating revenue for that tag to justify it. If revenue doesn't hold tag would be deleted after 6 months. So to guarantee any change i would need a proof of concept. Does it seem right @Makyen ? Am i right to presume that this statement holds true for any other change on MSO or SO?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Questions have to be pretty much identical to merge. Merging is different to marking as duplicates, as all the answers get put under the target question and so they need to make complete sense. There is nothing inherently wrong with having posts linked as duplicates - the caveat on that is the number of posts linked as duplicates as there does come a point when there's so many it just becomes untenable to go through them.

Soooo my point from all that yabbering on is: It's just as easy to raise a custom mod flag asking for posts to be merged. Creating a standard flag for merging questions is low on the list of priorities. There's a lot of other flag reasons that would come above that to be listed as a standard flag. The reason we limit the standard flag reasons, apart from UI, is there is a point (much like with lined duplicates) it becomes [counterproductive for people to wade through flag reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_user_interface_design) when writing out a simple custom flag will serve the same purpose.

[What is the correct procedure for requesting that two questions be merged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312091/what-is-the-correct-procedure-for-requesting-that-two-questions-be-merged)

Comment: I see merging as removing redundancy and repetition of data, therefore making this Q&A easier to navigate. I think there is no need to explain such basic concept as why easier navigation is in best intention for any website. The issue is that some flags generate overall redundancy, and some of the people that moderate them don't moderate via review queues but independently. This independent behaviour generates a lot of circular flags, since independant users will sometimes flag something even though original flag requirements are only loosely met.

Comment: @Danilo as mentioned, we're loathe to merge posts. It can only be done by moderators and is irreversible. People browsing linked posts is no real issue for the internet. Wading through loads of answers and options is harder than clicking on a fresh link. However I will not argue with you about UI design, although I will mention I mark student designs at a post graduate level, so I'm not entirely talking out of my hat.

Comment: This behaviour, leaves some Q&As unanswered but flagged and then referenced in another flag. Be it to broad, dup, or whatever. SO doesn't currently have any method (that i am aware of) to derive decision of most flags, so once Q or A is flagged it can stay flagged and nothing to do be done with it unless community account delete it after some number of years. Every language or aspect of it has its own synonyms, antonyms, homonyms ... so i see great value in flagged Q&A as metadata, that would benefit most suited answers, focus search history towards right topic and bre productive.

Comment: And, as so many told me (and you) merging questions isn't easy task... it is like hand washing dishes after lunch (no one likes it, but it is must be done). That is why i suggested , not new flag, not anything else...but an new tag in this Meta Stack Overflow. With this tag, users can help ( via answers to the questions with that tag ) mods do some work by actually working on editing part suggestions and ides before only minimal work needs to be done ( since community by itself has done most of it).