# Opinion-based close reason doesn't seem accurate for my question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, opinion-based

I don't understand how [Make dapper SQL be syntax colorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19668074/make-dapper-sql-be-syntax-colorized) is opinion-based. It's asking for a very specific technical task to be done, and the top upvoted answer gives a concrete and specific means to do that, using a specific plugin.

There is certainly more than one way to do the job, but that doesn't mean that this question is poor or doesn't help people. Many technical questions have more than one possible answer.

Comment: It's not really opinion based, but it's certainly asking for plugins / libraries, which is off-topic on SO... Although, _"Who knows what other options there might be."_ can be considered opinion-based.

Comment: Wouldn't "NEEDS FOCUS" be also a good close reason? The question is very, very ancient. Was it closed rrecently?

Comment: I'm afraid the wording reeks of [brainstorming ideas](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267282/2821954) which is usually too broad/opinion-based. Though, I guess the question can be salvaged into a simple how-to question, i.e. "How to add/enable syntax coloring for Dapper SQL in a C# project?".

Comment: Yeah, I think it seems fine; certainly not opinion based (one close voter did pick "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more").  I think it sounds more like an on-topic how-to question even if the answer is _likely_ a plugin, though one could imagine an IDE having a way to do it without one (e.g., some IDEs do colorize strings they recognize as SQL syntax).

Comment: Long story short: "how to" questions are hit and miss. If you have one, triple check how you phrase it.

Comment: I have edited the question to more clearly present the concrete "how can I solve this problem" point that is the essence of the question (and shouldn't be considered opinion based).

Comment: @Cerbrus The question (as it existed at the time of this discussion starting, as well as now) did NOT ask for plugins/libraries as you have asserted in your comment. It simply said "how can this be done"? It revealed certain thoughts on techniques that *could* solve the problem such as coding an entire plugin, but that was not what was being **asked** for. And the question doesn't turn into opinion-based simply because the asker, not knowing _any_ reasonable solution, merely revealed merely the belief that a plugin might be *one* way to solve the problem.

Comment: @SteveMarooni Yes, it was closed something like 2 days before this meta question was asked about it.

Comment: Whether this question is opinion based seems to be a matter of opinion.

Comment: Phrases like "And for a bonus [some separate question]" usually make questions too broad. Please ask one question per question.

Comment: For what it's worth, "*if you could invent your own programming language, how would you implement syntax coloring in <IDE>?*" is _way_ too broad for a site like Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This question is a little messy, and the wording could certainly get cleaned up a bit, but it is absolutely on topic. It's a practical, answerable question specific to programming about a software tool commonly used by programmers (Visual Studio IDE).

Lets examine both of the proposed close reasons:

#### Opinion-Based

The [official FAQ guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417487) that lives here on Meta Stack Overflow states (bold is mine):

> “*This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations.*”
>
> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to **be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than** facts, references, or **objective solutions**.

The proposed plugins in each answer are *objective solutions*. They either work, and highlight SQL within .NET Code in the Visual Studio IDE, or they do not. This precise, objective criteria for judging the value of each plugin is directly laid out in the question:

> If one ... [wanted] to get Dapper SQL strings in a C# project syntax colorized in Visual Studio (and for a bonus, syntax checked or even intellisense-capable!), how would one go about it?

The asker wants:

1. SQL Colorization
2. SQL syntax checking/ IntelliSense

The answers could be improved, perhaps, with more specific explanation about their given plugins, but they are certainly not "*based entirely on opinions rather than objective solutions*".

#### Seeking Recommendations

Starting again with the [official Meta FAQ guidance on this closure reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417480):

> ##### How we define Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more
>
> Recommendation questions are posts seeking off-site resources to solve the problem. **The question asks for what to use rather than how to do something**.

This question simply does not run afoul of that guideline. The opening line is a (again, perhaps busy) request for getting SQL syntax highlighting going, and specifically, word for word, "*how would one go about it*". They didn't ask for which library was best. They didn't ask for what plugin to use. They asked *how* to get highlighting. That's on-topic, plain and simple.

Having multiple answers suggest a plugin as a solution does not suddenly turn this question that's explicitly about "how" into an off-topic question about "what to use".

This question is not off-topic, and was rightly reopened.

(It could probably benefit from some fluff clean-up though.)

Answer (score 11):

As one of the close voters of that question, I shall try to explain my reasoning.

This looks, to me, sort of half way between "Opinion based" and "Seeking recommendations …". The text for the former, on the close vote pop-up is as follows (bold emphasis mine):

> This question is ***likely to be answered with opinions*** rather than
> facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to
> fact-based answers.

And, for "Seeking recommendations …", the text is:

> This question is ***likely to lead to*** opinion-based answers.

My decision ([from review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/34101854)) to vote-to-close wasn't a quick one, or one that I made lightly. I can see that it *may* be answered with facts but, when I looked at the *existing* answers, I saw that 2 out of the 3 (including the accepted answer) were, in fact, recommending third-party plug-ins. This tipped the balance, for me, towards casting the close vote.

Editing *may* have been an option were it a newer question without answers but I felt that, in this case, that was not really an appropriate action. However, I can fully understand that many users may disagree with my choice, here. There will often be a degree of subjectivity involved in whether or not to close such questions; if it is reopened, then I certainly won't be challenging that decision, either.

Comment: I don't understand how recommending plugins makes it opinion-based. The question doesn't ask for the best plugin among many. It doesn't even express the knowledge that there are *any* plugins that do the job. It asks for *any means possible*, including the asker writing a copious amount of code so solve the technical, IDE-based, non-opinion-based goal of getting SQL in strings to be syntax-colorized. It's really quite perplexing how the fact of there being plugin-based answers turns it into opinion-based. Q: How do I do X programming thing AT ALL? A: Try A, B, or C. No opinion there.

Comment: People tend to reach for "seeking recommendations" for cases like this because *every sane answer is going to be a recommendation*. Solving the problem entails using a plugin, because that's how syntax-coloring rules are communicated to the IDE. So either we are going to write our own plugin (that includes OP's "define a new language" suggestion, since there would still have to be a plugin for that "language") or use an existing one, and a "how do I write my own plugin" question would clearly and blatantly need more focus.

Comment: People may tend to reach for that close reason in cases like this, for precisely the reasons that @Karl described, but **that reach is incorrect**. That's not what the close reason is intended for. The documented, recommended way of asking for recommendations is to ask how to solve a problem, rather than asking for recommendations. The "seeking recommendations" close reason is literally only for questions that are seeking recommendations, meaning that they're asking for recommendations. How-to questions are not off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

The premise of this site is too answer any programming-related question a developer might have. IDE configuration is therefore on-topic.

People gotta realize that "How to let my IDE do X" will often result in "plugin Y can do that". It's just how it works, nowadays. You get a pluggable editor, and you make it an IDE through plugins.

So this is not offtopic nor opinion-based. The "no asking for libraries" rule must be seen in its spirit: you can't ask "what is your favorite library to do X", as that attracts spam and opinion-based answers, especially for paid libraries, which in itself is a problem that's nowadays way rarer than a decade or two ago.

Given the state of the ecosystem, and especially regarding IDEs like VS Code which runs entirely on plugins, I'd say questions like this are perfectly fine.

And yes, I consider VS Code to be an IDE, and yes, one should prevent using "weasel words" like "plugins" to not trigger such close votes.

Comment: "The premise of this site is too answer any programming-related question a developer might have. IDE configuration is therefore on-topic." IMO the site made a huge mistake by deciding that. The spirit of the site, as I always understood it, is that a question about programming is one in which *code is written in order to solve the underlying problem*.

Comment: @Karl that is not a mistake, in my opinion. Else we would not have Git (or other source control) questions or questions about programming concepts. I definitely do not want only answers which have to contain code, otherwise we'd have to visit 2-3 sites with different rules and crowds to answer all our programming needs. We can see on softwareengineering.stackexchange.com and codereview.stackexchange.com what that fragmentation does.

Comment: "Else we would not have Git (or other source control) questions or questions about programming concepts" Indeed. I would argue that at least some Git questions are off topic, as the questioner is not doing any programming. But that is a different can of worms.

Comment: @matt I have a _lot_ of complaints about Git questions, but not because there are non-programmers using it. What's the harm in that? My main problem is that there are (million-rep) users repeating the same answers over and over again.

Comment: @CodeCaster Definitely, but that in turn is prompted by the fact that people don't search before asking. Everyone seems to think they are the only person ever to have experienced a certain difficulty or to believe that they deserve personal hand-holding, both of which I find to be unbearably arrogant attitudes. Stack Overflow seems to breed a sense of entitlement. And whatever happened to RTFM?

Comment: What happened to RTFM? Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow decided that it would replace TFM with TFQ&A. So, now, if you fail to RTFQ&A, then your question shall be marked as a duplicate. If you fail to RTFM, then you've probably asked a question that usefully contributes to Stack Overflow's knowledge base and will help everyone else who has no time to or interest in RTFM.

Comment: @CodyGray yes, we agree this time. The point is that Q&A is simply a better way to present a lot of that material. TFM is designed to a) be systematic and b) explain what each piece does; that's the opposite of what people usually need, which is to *locate the right piece*. *Searching within* TFM gets you part of the way there, but it's a hack, and it also has no way to, e.g., accumulate metadata about the relative importance of the pieces.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still a manual-reader. But I recognize that this is only one of the many ways that I'm weird.

Answer (score 2):

I am the first close-voter.

The question looks opinion based to me.

Looking at the answers, my first thought was Resource Request. But, question is not asking for any resource explicitly. So, it is not a Resource Request in my opinion.

My other thought was was Too Broad. It involves VS versions and Dapper ORM (I do not understood what the SQL highlighting have to do with Dapper; IMO, it is same thing with or without Dapper). Apart from that, question does mention "wild ideas" but does not mention any step taken towards those which does not worked as expected for OP. Even so, I am not fully convinced for this close reason.

I choose Opinion Based because there may be multiple ways to colorize the sql.

> There is certainly more than one way to do the job, but that doesn't mean that this question is poor or doesn't help people. Many technical questions have more than one possible answer.

Yes; I agree. There might be many ways to solve the problem and that alone does not make a question Opinion Based.
But, in this particular case, there are also multiple factors involved. Visual Studio Version and the Dapper micro ORM to say.

OP explicitly asked for "options". A quote from the question:

> Who knows what other options there might be.

There might be too many options based on "opinion" of the answerer.

Comment: @ErikE: You write SQL query and pass it to Dapper for execution. But, you may write SQL without using Dapper (with ADO.NET for example) and want it to be colorized. Colorizing SQL in Visual Studio is neither in scope of Dapper not it is Dapper specific.

Comment: @ErikE: `then you may not be qualified to decide if the question is opinion-based` I may be wrong but AFAIK moderation on SO does not always need deep understanding of technology in question. Considering you have 48K points, your post script comment feel unfriendly/unkind to me.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback about my comment. I deleted it in favor of a replacement:

I asked the question because I truly had no clue how to get started. I spent some  time searching the internet and problem-solving. While the question is not strictly/only about coding, IDE usage questions ARE on topic. SQL Syntax highlighting does have a relation to Dapper, even though Dapper can take its SQL strings via variables as well as via string literals, because that is the use case present when asking the question. But mentioning Dapper doesn't make it more or less opinion-based.